# NPM versions during development and production

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

From what I have read it is a good idea to use the same version of Node.js throughout the development and production phases of an app.

Is this also true of NPM? It looks as if NVM is keeping specific versions of NPM together with specific versions of Node.js inside the .nvm directory. However, although I can see from the NVM documentation how to make sure you run an app with a particular version of Node.js, I can not see how to make sure that a particular version of NPM is used for a particular app. For example if I run the command `npm install package` from the root directory of an app I think it will use the default version of NPM not the specific version associated with the Node.js version specified in the .nvmrc file of the app.

Do I need to be consistent in the version of NPM I use during app development and production? If the answer is yes how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

When we start a Project using Nodejs a file named package.json is created automatically and it keeps track of all the dependencies in the ongoing Project. So you do not need to worry about the versions, you just have to start the project and all the dependencies will be taken care of. 
Suppose you need to share your codes(like Git) then you just need to share your codes and package.json file that will do the trick.

Comment: I think the version of Node.js and NPM is not kept in package.json. So, (at least for Node.js) NVM helps to ensure you keep to the same version of Node.js (and NPM??)